# Loop over columns and calculate relative change within groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset (df) and want to achieve df_goal. That is to create a new variable that captures the relative change within groups from value1 and value2. In my real dataset I have a lot of columns, so I want to find a solution that loops over columns and add new ones along the way.

I have tried versions of the snippet below but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col + 'REL_CGH'] = df.groupby(['GROUP']).apply((df.col / dfcol[0]) * 100)
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
             'VALUE1': [5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8],
             'VALUE2': [11, 16, 21, 321, 401, 423]})

df_goal = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
             'VALUE1': [5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 8],
             'VALUE2': [11, 16, 21, 321, 401, 423],
             'VALUE1_REL_CHG': [100, 120, 140, 100, 167, 267],
             'VALUE2_REL_CHG' :[100, 145, 191, 100, 174, 183]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first value per groups of all columns defined in list `cols`, divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), round and convert to integers, use [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and last append to original:

```
cols = ['VALUE1','VALUE2']
df = (df.join(df[cols].div(df.groupby(['GROUP'])[cols].transform('first'))
                      .mul(100)
                      .round()
                      .astype(int)
                      .add_suffix('_REL_CGH')))

print (df)
  GROUP  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE1_REL_CGH  VALUE2_REL_CGH
0     A       5      11             100             100
1     A       6      16             120             145
2     A       7      21             140             191
3     B       3     321             100             100
4     B       5     401             167             125
5     B       8     423             267             132
```

Your solution should be changed with lambda function, but is slowier if large DataFrame:

```
for col in cols:
    df[col + 'REL_CGH'] = df.groupby(['GROUP'])[col].apply(lambda x: (x / x.iloc[0]) * 100)
```

Comment: Nice! Your second solution work well on my real world dataset. The first one removes my original columns and replaces them with the new ones for some reason.

Comment: In my real world dataset I also have dates as index, so perhaps that causes problem for your first very elegant solution.